# Does boxplot group data before plotting implicitly?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from which I am trying to create a boxplot.

The dataframe is as follows

```
CopyNumber        LOH
     2            yes
     2            no
     3            yes
     4            no
     3            maybe
     8            maybe
     2            yes
     2            no
     3            yes
     4            no
     3            maybe
     8            maybe
```

I would like to create a boxplot where the x-axis is LOH status and y-axis is CopyNumber. 
In my attempt the boxplot only creates two groups rather than three (for yes, no and maybe). How can I get the boxplot to create these groupings rather than me having to create these groups explicitly?

Comment: OK didnt know about ~ .That's superuseful

Comment: Can you add as an answer so I can vote for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
boxplot(CopyNumber~LOH, df1)
```

Data:

```
#data
df1 <- read.table(text="CopyNumber        LOH
2            yes
2            no
3            yes
4            no
3            maybe
8            maybe
2            yes
2            no
3            yes
4            no
3            maybe
8            maybe",header=TRUE)
```

Assign `boxplot` to a variable as:

```
x <- boxplot(CopyNumber~LOH, df1)
```

Then you can see the data used for plotting, e.g.:

```
x$names
#[1] "maybe" "no"    "yes"
```